# Inserting Read More Tag in Widget

Tags: widgets

My "About Me" widget on the sidebar is too long and I want to insert a "Read More" tag.

I can't find how to do it. Can anyone provide simple instructions? I can do basic HTML but can't seem to find where the code is for widgets.

Comment: Please share more information about your setup. Do you use a custom theme or a bought one?

Comment: Hi @Laxmana, I am using the Olsen Light theme. This is the sidebar.php text that's currently there:

<div class="sidebar sidebar-right" role="complementary" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
 <?php
  if( is_page() && is_active_sidebar( 'page' ) ) {
   dynamic_sidebar( 'page' );
  } else {
   dynamic_sidebar( 'blog' );
  }
 ?>
</div><!-- /sidebar -->

Anything more you need to know?

Comment: You could use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-showhide/  this plugin. It allows to wrap your text on the shortcode and shows hide/show effect as Read more

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy.

Usually your widget is supposed to be held on `sidebar.php`
In `sidebar.php` you may have been call the function `the_content()` to extract 'About Me' text.

In stead of calling `the_content()` you need to call your own created function [suppose, `read_more()`] which should be defined in `functions.php` like this way:

```
function read_more($limit){
    $post_content = explode(' ', get_the_content());
    $less_content = array_slice($post_content,0, $limit);
    echo implode(' ', $less_content);
}
```

Now, mentioning an argument, call the `read_more()`function in anywhere you need, perhaps in sidebar.php
**Note that,** first, needs to **make Query** and then **call the function** this way:

```
<?php
    $content_text = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'text'));
      while($content_text->have_post()) : $content_text->the_post();
?>
       <p> <?php read_more(15); ?> </p> 
       <p> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More </a> </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

where, integer value indicates 15 number of words to be shown up there.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you perfectionist1 but that is too complicated for me! Is there not a plugin that will do the job?

Comment: This is the sidebar.php code as it stands:

<div class="sidebar sidebar-right" role="complementary" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
 <?php
  if( is_page() && is_active_sidebar( 'page' ) ) {
   dynamic_sidebar( 'page' );
  } else {
   dynamic_sidebar( 'blog' );
  }
 ?>
</div><!-- /sidebar -->

Comment: In your case, you will find the function the_content() onto page.php 
and blog.php as well.
If you unable to replace the code. Then you would share your code so that I can try to help you.